# How to remove "undefined" value from Prestashop deleted Firstname and Lastname invoice address fields

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I have removed Firstname and Lastname input fields from Prestashop billing/invoice address form in checkout and all works fine - checkout process is ok.

But not filled firstname and lastname inputs throw "undefined" values to database and looks not good.
[image]

When i removed this field values from database from undefined to nothing (clean field) all working good. How to prevent Prestashop to write this fields with undefined values like here?
[image]

I have change class **Address.php** file from

```
'lastname' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
'firstname' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
```

to

```
'lastname' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName'/*, 'required' => true*/, 'size' => 32),
'firstname' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName'/*, 'required' => true*/, 'size' => 32),
```

and also change type of the database **lastname** and **firstname** fields "to be like" **address2** -> default *NULL*

No success

Comment: Where is the code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone just updated. Maybe i have to change type from  isName to isAddress?

Comment: You should remove the column from database and clean up all the code handling that field. Set `display_errors = on`, `error_reporting = -1`, `display_startup_errors = on` in php/apache2/php.ini on your development system. Use xdebug for debugging.

Comment: Thanks but its too complicated. input value="(one space here)" does the job perfectly. I have post answer to my question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is:**

- hide all inputs via css (in my case *.hidden* class via Boostrap framework)
- make input value as value="(one space here)"

Work like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: this answer is *very* 'hacky', will always break on upgrades and might result in errors in other areas you may not be considering at the moment. Do yourself a favor and take the time to do this "the right way" (use overrides when changing core classes etc.). Trust me, i used to do prestashop modifications like that all the time, almost always ends up costing more time afterwards...

Comment: @defuzed yes You have right but in my case the problem was solved and hopefuly works like it should so far. This data is just null and nothing will harm